# How do you find out how much data has been transferred over Wifi, 3G or EDGE on Android?

Tags: android

I'm trying to write an Android widget that shows how much data has been transferred over 3G/WIFI/EDGE but I can't seem to find the API call, even though other widgets do this.  Does anyone know what the API calls are to get the data usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, found it, android.net.TrafficStats.

Comment: Actaully, TrafficStats is 2.2 only.  Turns out you have to dig in /sys/class/net/statistics to find it on older phones.